# Как вставить выбранную картинку из большого количества картинок background-ом?

Tags: javascript, css, json, reactjs

Всем привет! Имею в json-e массив объектов вида:

```
var pictures = [{
    image: './images/img1.png',
    'description': 'defjffhhf'
}, {
    image: './images/img1.png',
    'description': 'defjffhhf'
}, {
    image: './images/img3.png',
    'description': 'defjffhhf'
}, {
    image: './images/img4.png',
    'description': 'defjffhhf'
}]
```

и т.д. их около 50 штук. Я рандомным образом через **js** выбираю одну из них.

Как мне правильно передавать одну из этих картинок в компонент и вcтавлять background-ом ?
Делаю через инлайн-стили
 `backgroundImage: 'url(${this.props.image})'`
Может, есть еще способы, чтобы не использовать инлайн-стили? И при этом так не работает, приходится прописывать полный урл к картинке.
через добавление модификатора работает. Добавляю дополинтельный класс и в стилях прописываю уже
   `backgroung-image: url('./images/img1.png')`

Хотелось бы как-нибудь через модификатор, но делать 50 штук модификаторов с названиями картинки тоже как-то не очень

Comment: Почему не прописывать стиль блоку программно? Например: document.body.style.backgroundImage = url;

Comment: у меня на react-е все это

Comment: Дайте кусок кода как вы делаете все это

Comment: А где у вас код `react` ?

Answer (score 0):

можно через styled-components:

```
render() {
    const {color} = this.state;
    const Div = styled.div`
        color: ${color}
    `;
    return (
        <Div>color text</Div>
    );
}
```

Соответственно, в styled.div вместо color - написать свой css код, а в качестве переменной вставлять путь к выбранной картинке